# Google account: Can retrieve the picture from openid? Can I get it with OAuth to google?

Tags: php, rest, oauth, google-account

I need to retrieve the name, email and picture from a google account.
I am already using the openid to make the user login with it's google acc.

Can I have the picture URL from the openid proccess?

with OAuth I cant'seem to find the right scope to retrieve this information... See this link:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html

there is a list of scopes that you can fetch with REST api to google and I didnt't see the one related to the profile.

Btw, I am using PHP and the openid is already working, but didn't start with the oauth untill I know if I can(and need) retrieve the picture (because email and name already comes within the openid proccess)

thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can retrieve the picture URL with the Google Contacts Data API : see http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_photo

Then you must authenticate your requests with OAuth. If you already use OpenID, you can now use the hybid protocol OpenId/OAuth : see http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#oauth